# In Batch File loop through to directories to find sub dirs and files, and when exists in target rename to _OLD and copy new file to target

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am building a small automated deployment pipeline for an application. 
I am very new to batch files, created a few ones so far with success, but this particular one is driving me nuts.

What I want:

in an inputpath, there can be files and/or subdirectories with files.
If these exist in the targetpath, then the the files in the targetpath need to be be renamed to file_OLD.extension.

When this is done the files from inputpath need to be copied there.

If the file, or sub directory with file not exists, the sub directory needs to be created and the file needs to be placed there.

What I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set inputpath=P:\Deployment\1.DeployToTST\Template
set targetpath=\\<servername>\Template

for /f %%a in ('dir "%inputpath%"/a-d/b/-p/s^|find /v ""') do (

if exist %targetpath%\%%a (
xcopy "%targetpath%\%%a" "%targetpath%/%%a_OLD" /Y
xcopy /S "%%a" "%targetpath%\%%a" /Y /I /K

) ELSE  (

xcopy /S "%%a" "%targetpath\%%a%" /Y /I /K)

)
```

I feel that the logic is right (it is not rocket science after all), however I cant seem to get it working. 
as %%a seems to be taking the entire full file path:

```
P:\Deployment\1.DeployToTST\Template\template1.ctx
P:\Deployment\1.DeployToTST\Template\template1\template1.ctx
```

I actually need for %%a to be:

```
 template1.ctx
 template1\template1.ctx
```

file extensions differ, so do the subdirectories in my inputpath.

Any help is very welcome (besides the tips of stopping with DOS scritping ;-) )

Comment: It's not DOS scripting! Anyway, what if there is already a file `*_OLD.*` in the target location?

Comment: Answered on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8645)

Answer (score 0):

#### I actually need for `%%a` to be:

> ```
> template1.ctx
> template1\template1.ctx
> ```

Use the following:

```
set _temp=%%a
rem remove P:\Deployment\1.DeployToTST\Template\ from the string
set _result=%_temp:P:\Deployment\1.DeployToTST\Template\=%
```

Then use `%_result%` in place of `%%a`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.